# Can I directly use the accented syllable in database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, non-ascii-characters

I am building a Rails application which needs the list of countries,cities.City should at least contain 100,000 peoples. I have found the data from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_towns_and_cities_with_100,000_or_more_inhabitants/country%3a_A-B).But I need a clarification city names contains some special letters.

```
Durrës - ë
Vicente López - ó
São Paulo - ã
```

I have googled and found these are accented syllable.

My question is

```
Can I directly insert these values into the database?
Can I search the database without any problem?
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you set your database to store values as utf-8 you should be able to store a wide range of such values without problem.

When it comes to sorting and comparing the important thing is which collation you ask the database to use. In a nutshell a collation is a set of rules saying how strings are compared, for example how is é sorted relative to e, is ß equal to ss and so on.

When using full text search (solr, sphinx etc) you should ensure that your stop words, choice of stemmer and so on are Unicode aware